# How to send attachment in email using ampscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

How to Create an email using the AMPscript AttachFile() function in the exact target content area that will send an email with an attachment using SOAP API and REST API

Comment: It may be helpful to add some more details to your question, mostly what you're trying to achieve and how you want to use both SOAP & REST APIs.

Comment: I am using this exacttarget in Mule implementation. We are currently using to send emails with out attachments. We are using SOAP based approach.

Now we are planning to create a rest service that will trigger a email with attachment.

Need to do a POC by using ampscript. Any help in this regard will be usefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the AMPscript attachFile function, you must have the feature turned on for the account. If you are having difficulties getting it to work I would start with contacting your ExactTarget Admin to insure that feature is available and if not get with your ExactTarget representative to get pricing. Also, here is a link to the wiki specific to attaching files to emails: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_attachments/

Comment: Great answer mate. Is It posible to attach block files stored in Azure Storage?